# Java form submit with concatenated link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have a form i would like to be submitted and re-directed to a different page which will eventually be a concatenated hyperlink but i cant seem to get the function to even change page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Email 1:<input type="text" id="email"><br>
<input type="submit" onClick="link()">
</form>
</body>
</html>


function link()
{
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"
}
```

won't seem to work where have i gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change  the onclick to the following:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="link(); return false">
```

Or:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return link();">

<script>
function link()
{
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    return false;
}
</script>
```

It will prevent the form is going to be sumitted to the same page again by the standard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute should be `onclick` instead of `onClick`

```
<input type="submit" onclick="link()">
```

And because your input type is submit so it will try to submit the form when you click on that button. Add `onsubmit="return false"` to the `form` tag to prevent that.

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
```

And the script should inside `script` tag. So finally your html file should look like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return false">
Email 1:<input type="text" id="email"><br>
<input type="submit" onclick="link();">
</form>
<script  type="text/javascript">
function link()
{
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    return false;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```